# Informatica Ultra Messaging - 6.7 Exception in initializer

Tags: java, informatica

I'm getting the following exception in initializer:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.latencybusters.lbm.LBMInit.init_once(LBMInit.java:86)
        at com.latencybusters.lbm.LBMContextAttributes.<clinit>(LBMContextAttributes.java:304)
...

Caused by: com.latencybusters.lbm.LBMRuntimeException: Can't locate LBMContext handleMessage method
        at com.latencybusters.lbm.LBMInit.<init>(LBMInit.java:77)
        at com.latencybusters.lbm.LBMInit.<init>(LBMInit.java:36)
        at com.latencybusters.lbm.LBMInit$LBMInitHolder.<clinit>(LBMInit.java:82)
```

Using Informatica Ultra Messaging - 6.7 on a Linux machine. I could't find any information online and also there is no other information in the exception itself. Disassembly of `LBMContext` shows that there is actually a method `private void handleMessage(long msgptr, String source, String topic_name, Object source_clientd)`

Has anybody experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

Using the wrong version of the *native* library (thanks Informatica for the meaningful error message)